# Previous/Next Web Page Links Heuristics?

Tags: html, url, web-crawler, href, heuristics

I'm looking for a list of heuristics, given an HTML document and/or a set of URLs on a web page, that will give a set of URLs that are previous/next links from that page.  Also, assume that you are given the base URL.  I do not require to know if a link is specifically a next or previous URL, just that it is one of those two.

I've got a short list going already:

- **Same domain and path as the URL, but different query parameters.**

  - base: abc.com/story
  - next/previous: abc.com/story?p=2

    - or
  - base: abc.com/story.html?p=5
  - next/previous: abc.com/story.html?p=3
- **URL is the same as the base URL except a numerical path element.**

  - base: abc.com/story
  - next/previous: abc.com/story/2
- **Several links nearby each other in the DOM/HTML.**

  - I know this could also be like a header/footer, I would have to account for that somehow...any ideas?
- **Links whose text is a number or whose test is a word like "Next", "Previous", "First", "Last", "Back", "Forward", etc...**

I know I can never be perfect at this, but I would like to get as much coverage and as many heuristics as I can to hope for a nice mix or quantity and quality.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, don't you mean just grab all links on a page that don't have a different domain?

Comment: No.  I am interested in finding **pagination** or **next/previous** links on pages.  e.g. On a Google search page, I want to find the 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 links at the bottom of the page.  However, If I was already on page 4, I would want to find the page 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 links.

For this question, I want to gather a list of heuristics I can use ,while examining an HTML document and/or just the multi-set of links on a page, to help identify next/previous or pagination links.

I want these heuristics to be generic to all sites.

Does that make more sense?